# elasticsearch js api upsert with multiple fields match

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch in a node environment. 
This is my data model :

```
"_source": {
    "repo_id": "ecom-test",
    "pr_id": "1",
    "pr_status": "approved",
    "date_created": "2016-12-14T12:55:50.317Z",
    "date_modified": "2016-12-14T12:55:50.317Z",
    "comments": [
      {
        "tuple": {
          "reviewee": "Max",
          "reviewer": "Vic"
        },
        "nb": "1",
        "type": "typo"
      },
      {
        "tuple": {
          "reviewee": "Antoine",
          "reviewer": "Vic"
        },
        "nb": "2",
        "type": "logic"
      }
    ]
}
```

I add comments using the following code :

```
client.update({
    index: 'loreal',
    type: 'reviews',
    id: reviewID,
    body: {
        script: {
            inline: "ctx._source.comments.add(params.comment)",
            lang: "painless",
            params: {
                comment: {
                    tuple: {
                        reviewee: data.reviewee,
                        reviewer: data.reviewer
                    },
                    nb: data.nb,
                    type: data.type
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

But when a comment with the same "reviewee", "reviewer" AND "logic" already exists i would like to update the "nb" attribute instead of creating a new item in the "comments" array.

I thought i would first make a search but I can't find a way to make a search that matches any element of the array "comments" that has those three values.

I really hope you guys can give me a hand with this, it's been a long time I am searching =s.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Given the struct of your document, I would have defined the comment field like a nested object: see the documentation example which is pretty close to your use case: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html#nested-objects

Considering that you got in param the reviewee value, I would use the combination of nested query and bool query. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/nested-query.html

```
{
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "comments",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "match": {
                        "comments.tuple.reviewee": "your reviewee"
                    }
                }, {
                    "match": {
                        "comments.tuple.reviewer": "your reviewee"
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "comments.type": "logic"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the test I wrote:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "item": {
      "properties": {
        "comments": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}





POST test/item
{ "comments": [
      {
        "tuple": {
          "reviewee": "Max",
          "reviewer": "Max"
        },
        "nb": "1",
        "type": "logic"
      },
      {
        "tuple": {
          "reviewee": "Antoine",
          "reviewer": "Vic"
        },
        "nb": "2",
        "type": "logic"
      }
    ]
}

POST test/item 
{
    "comments": [
      {
        "tuple": {
          "reviewee": "Max",
          "reviewer": "Max"
        },
        "nb": "1",
        "type": "test"
      },
      {
        "tuple": {
          "reviewee": "Antoine",
          "reviewer": "Vic"
        },
        "nb": "2",
        "type": "logic"
      }
    ]
}

POST test/item 
{
    "comments": [
      {
        "tuple": {
          "reviewee": "Max",
          "reviewer": "Mac"
        },
        "nb": "1",
        "type": "logic"
      },
      {
        "tuple": {
          "reviewee": "Antoine",
          "reviewer": "Vic"
        },
        "nb": "2",
        "type": "logic"
      }
    ]
}

GET /test/item/_search
{
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "comments",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "match": {
                        "comments.tuple.reviewee": "Max"
                    }
                }, {
                    "match": {
                        "comments.tuple.reviewer": "Max"
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "comments.type": "logic"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately it wasn't exactly what i was looking for but it helped me a lot with another issue. I finally decided to create a new document instead of updating the previous one. This way I don't need to do complicate updates, and i can keep history of the documents.